# Easy way to force pauses in an AVSpeechSynthesizer utterance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to speak a long passage. However, there are some sections of the text where I want the speaker to pause for a moment before continuing. Is there a trivial way to just, say, add some special character into the `NSString` used to create the utterance that will force a pause? Or am I going to have to split this up into several separate utterances and manually delay between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate's [willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate/speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:)

You could check for a special character there, call `pauseSpeakingAtBoundary` if you find it, and then resume after a set amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert two minus signs:

```
NSString *string = @"Hi--Dan";
```